# Are normal subgroups of a matrix group a matrix group?

Tags: lie-algebras, linear-groups

I came across this question but I'm not sure how to approach it; My thought process is that by definition all subgroups are groups, then why would it be a different case for matrices? What are some cases that I have to consider?

Comment: What is your definition of a matrix group?

Comment: My interpretation of a matrix group is a set of nxn matrices that is closed under multiplication, is associative, has an identity matrix, and each of the matrices are invertible, do correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix group is just a set of matrices with the group structure being matrix multiplication! A subgroup of a group is just a subset with the same group structure (in particular this subset is closed under the group action and inverses exist). So any subgroup of a matrix group is a matrix group (you don’t need normality). You just restrict the set of matrices you’re working with!

Comment: thank you for your response, I understand everything you said except the last sentence, can you elaborate on it? Are you saying that the normality condition reduces the cardinality of the matrix subgroup/subset?

Comment: @gradual_gradient they mean that in particular subgroups are groups when restricted, normal or otherwise. It's not the cardinality but membership that gets smaller.